# Make an old server more power efficient - HP DL380 G7

Tags: hp, electrical-power

i recently picked on ebay an old HP DL380 G7, i think it was a great deal, lots of disk space and a very low price, for what I need, it was a great deal.

These are the specs:

**CPU:** 2 x INTEL XEON E5530 2.40GHz 8MB QUAD CORE CPU

**RAM:** 8GB

**HDD:** 2 x GENERIC 600GB 15k 3.5" SAS - 4x HP 2TB 6G 7.2K 3.5" SAS

**RAID CONTROLLER:** P410i/256MB

**PSU:** 2 x 460W HOT PLUG PSU

It does not have to do very heavy work, it is used mostly as a storage and backup device, the cpu idle at about 3-4% but the power consumption is very high. The ILO report 150W, even a power meter report 150W (wow, i didn't expect that to be so accurate). My PC that is much powerfull idle at about 60W.

So what is it using so much power? What i should change for better power consumption (CPU, PSU ecc).

Maybe it's normal that servers use so much power? (i don't think so), are maybe the 6 disk that use so much power?

Here there is the screenshot of the power meter page:
[Power Meter Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPHWn.jpg)

Comment: I disagree with answers below, you can reduce power usage by properly setting up your bios. There is one pdf across web which determines and cover all settings related to power. There is much to do, but with ssd pcie card and pc3L (Low power ram) I could get 60-80 watt idle with this machine. However it depend greatly if your workload and needs. Reach me at panther.software if you need help

Answer (score 1):

150W for a dual socket, Nehalem-EP based server is not bad. After all, servers of that generation all have relatively high platform idle power consumption.

It is absolutely normal and expected that your PC consume much less power: it probably is a much newer, single socket system with lower-power DDR module and a smaller lithography CPU.

Comment: yes i know it, In fact, I asked what I could upgrade to make it more efficient. I don't want to upgrade everything right know, only the most energy-intensive parts

Comment: The high power consumption depends on the old platform. You can't upgrade anything to significantly lower its power consumption.